# Is there a relationship between a stellar-mass black hole and its host galaxy?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, galaxies

Out of curiosity, are there any relationships between stellar-mass black holes and their host galaxy? I am asking because I have read about how there is a relationship between a supermassive black hole in the centre of a galaxy and the velocity dispersion of their host bulges: the $(M-\sigma)%$ relationship.